# Can someone give a high level explanation of the purpose of a .d.ts file, and how to use the one for jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I am required to use TypeScript for a University assignment.  Part of my project involves multiple ajax requests, so I figured jQuery would be a good way to go.  How would I use TypeScript to write a jQuery ajax resquest, and how does what I write come from the jquery.d.ts file?

Comment: This comes across as more of a *how to get my homework done faster without doing any research* question ... read the manual

Answer (score 0):

> How would I use TypeScript to write a jQuery ajax resquest, and how does what I write come from the jquery.d.ts file

A `.d.ts` files tell TypeScript about *JavaScript* that is available for consumption from your TypeScript.

e.g. `window` is available for consumption in TypeScript because it is *declared* in `lib.d.ts`. So `jquery.d.ts` declares `$` (and other stuff) so that you can use JQuery (JavaScript) from TypeScript in a type safe manner.